# PHP load classes

Tags: php, apache2

I have a class loader like this :

```
function __autoload($classname){
require_once CLASSES_DIR . "/" . $classname . ".class.php";
}
```

and it correctly sets the URL of any classes.
The problem is that when an instance of a class is tried to be created in the index.php (line 13):

```
$pdo = PDOWrapper::instance();
```

The browser shows a page like this:

```
validateDriver($driver)) { throw new Exception('DATABASE WRAPPER::error, the database you wish to connect to is not supported by your install of PHP.'); } if (isset($this->pdo_master)) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::warning, attempting to config master after connection exists'); } $this->config_master = array( 'driver' => $driver, 'host' => $host, 'name' => $name, 'user' => $user, 'password' => $password, 'port' => $port ); } /** * method configSlave * - configure a connection to a slave (can be called multiple times) * * @param host - the host name of the db to connect to * @param name - the database name * @param user - the user name * @param password - the users password * @param port (optional) - the port to connect using, default to 3306 * @param driver - the dsn prefix */ public function configSlave($host, $name, $user, $password, $port=null, $driver='mysql') { if (!$this->validateDriver($driver)) { throw new Exception('DATABASE WRAPPER::error, the database you wish to connect to is not supported by your install of PHP.'); } if (isset($this->pdo_slave)) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::warning, attempting to config slave after connection exists'); } if (!isset($this->config_slaves)) { $this->config_slaves = array(); } $this->config_slaves[] = array( 'driver' => $driver, 'host' => $host, 'name' => $name, 'user' => $user, 'password' => $password, 'port' => $port ); } /** * method createConnection. * - create a PDO connection using the credentials provided * * @param driver - the dsn prefix * @param host - the host name of the db to connect to * @param name - the database name * @param user - the user name * @param password - the users password * @param port (optional) - the port to connect using, default to 3306 * @return PDO object with a connection to the database specified */ protected function createConnection($driver, $host, $name, $user, $password, $port=null) { die( var_dump(PDO::getAvailableDrivers())); if (!$this->validateDriver($driver)) { throw new Exception('DATABASE WRAPPER::error, the database you wish to connect to is not supported by your install of PHP.'); } // attempt to create pdo object and connect to the database try { //@TODO the following drivers are NOT supported yet: odbc, ibm, informix, 4D // build the connection string from static constants based on the selected PDO Driver. if ($driver == "sqlite" || $driver == "sqlite2") { $connection_string = $driver.':'.$host; } elseif ($driver == "sqlsrv") { $connection_string = "sqlsrv:Server=".$host.";Database=".$name; } elseif ($driver == "firebird" || $driver == "oci") { $connection_string = $driver.":dbname=".$name; } else { $connection_string = $driver.':host='.$host.';dbname='.$name; } // add the port if one was specified if (!empty($port)) { $connection_string .= "port=$port"; } // initialize the PDO object $new_connection = new PDO($connection_string, $user, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")); // set the error mode $new_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // return the new connection return $new_connection; } // handle any exceptions by catching them and returning false catch (PDOException $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; return false; } catch(Exception $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; return false; } } /** * method getMaster. * - grab the PDO connection to the master DB */ protected function getMaster() { // if we have not been configured, use hard coded values if (!isset($this->config_master)) { $this->config_master = array( 'driver' => self::DB_DSN_PREFIX_MASTER, 'host' => self::DB_HOST_MASTER, 'name' => self::DB_NAME_MASTER, 'user' => self::DB_USER_MASTER, 'password' => self::DB_PASSWORD_MASTER, 'port' => self::DB_PORT_MASTER ); } // if we have not created the master db connection yet, create it now if (!isset($this->pdo_master)) { $this->pdo_master = $this->createConnection( $this->config_master['driver'], $this->config_master['host'], $this->config_master['name'], $this->config_master['user'], $this->config_master['password'], $this->config_master['port'] ); } return $this->pdo_master; } /** * method getSlave. * - grab the PDO connection to the slave DB, create it if not there */ protected function getSlave() { // if we have not created a slave db connection, create it now if (!isset($this->pdo_slave)) { // if no slaves were configured, use hardcoded values if (!isset($this->config_slaves)) { $i = 1; while (defined('self::SLAVE' . $i . '_HOST') && constant('self::SLAVE' . $i . '_HOST')) { $this->config_slaves[] = array( 'driver' => constant('self::SLAVE' . $i . '_DSN_PREFIX'), 'host' => constant('self::SLAVE' . $i . '_HOST'), 'name' => constant('self::SLAVE' . $i . '_NAME'), 'user' => constant('self::SLAVE' . $i . '_USER'), 'password' => constant('self::SLAVE' . $i . '_PASSWORD'), 'port' => constant('self::SLAVE' . $i . '_PORT'), ); $i++; } } // if no slaves are configured, use the master connection if (empty($this->config_slaves)) { $this->pdo_slave = $this->getMaster(); } // if we have slaves, randomly choose one to use for this request and connect else { $random_slave = $this->config_slaves[array_rand($this->config_slaves)]; $this->pdo_slave = $this->createConnection( $random_slave['driver'], $random_slave['host'], $random_slave['name'], $random_slave['user'], $random_slave['password'], $random_slave['port'] ); } } return $this->pdo_slave; } /** * method select. * - retrieve information from the database, as an array * * @param string $table - the name of the db table we are retreiving the rows from * @param array $params - associative array representing the WHERE clause filters * @param int $limit (optional) - the amount of rows to return * @param int $start (optional) - the row to start on, indexed by zero * @param array $order_by (optional) - an array with order by clause * @param bool $use_master (optional) - use the master db for this read * @return mixed - associate representing the fetched table row, false on failure */ public function select($table, $params = null, $limit = null, $start = null, $order_by=null, $use_master = false) { // building query string $sql_str = "SELECT * FROM $table"; // append WHERE if necessary $sql_str .= ( count($params)>0 ? ' WHERE ' : '' ); $add_and = false; // add each clause using parameter array if (empty($params)) { $params = array(); } foreach ($params as $key=>$val) { // only add AND after the first clause item has been appended if ($add_and) { $sql_str .= ' AND '; } else { $add_and = true; } // append clause item $sql_str .= "$key = :$key"; } // add the order by clause if we have one if (!empty($order_by)) { $sql_str .= ' ORDER BY'; $add_comma = false; foreach ($order_by as $column => $order) { if ($add_comma) { $sql_str .= ', '; } else { $add_comma = true; } $sql_str .= " $column $order"; } } // now we attempt to retrieve the row using the sql string try { // decide which database we are selecting from $pdo_connection = $use_master ? $this->getMaster() : $this->getSlave(); $pdoDriver = $pdo_connection->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME); //@TODO MS SQL Server & Oracle handle LIMITs differently, for now its disabled but we should address it later. $disableLimit = array("sqlsrv", "mssql", "oci"); // add the limit clause if we have one if (!is_null($limit) && !in_array($pdoDriver, $disableLimit)) { $sql_str .= ' LIMIT '.(!is_null($start) ? "$start, ": '')."$limit"; } $pstmt = $pdo_connection->prepare($sql_str); // bind each parameter in the array foreach ($params as $key=>$val) { $pstmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $val); } $pstmt->execute(); // now return the results, depending on if we want all or first row only if ( !is_null($limit) && $limit == 1 ) { return $pstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); } else { return $pstmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); } } catch(PDOException $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; return false; } catch(Exception $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; return false; } } /** * method selectMaster. * - retrieve information from the master database, as an array * * @param table - the name of the db table we are retreiving the rows from * @param params - associative array representing the WHERE clause filters * @param int $limit (optional) - the amount of rows to return * @param int $start (optional) - the row to start on, indexed by zero * @param array $order_by (optional) - an array with order by clause * @return mixed - associate representing the fetched table row, false on failure */ public function selectMaster($table, $params = array(), $limit = null, $start = null, $order_by=null) { return $this->select($table, $params, $limit, $start, $order_by, true); } /** * method selectFirst. * - retrieve the first row returned from a select statement * * @param table - the name of the db table we are retreiving the rows from * @param params - associative array representing the WHERE clause filters * @param array $order_by (optional) - an array with order by clause * @return mixed - associate representing the fetched table row, false on failure */ public function selectFirst($table, $params = array(), $order_by=null) { return $this->select($table, $params, 1, null, $order_by); } /** * method selectFirstMaster. * - retrieve the first row returned from a select statement using the master database * * @param table - the name of the db table we are retreiving the rows from * @param params - associative array representing the WHERE clause filters * @param array $order_by (optional) - an array with order by clause * @return mixed - associate representing the fetched table row, false on failure */ public function selectFirstMaster($table, $params = array(), $order_by=null) { return $this->select($table, $params, 1, null, $order_by, true); } /** * method delete. * - deletes rows from a table based on the parameters * * @param table - the name of the db table we are deleting the rows from * @param params - associative array representing the WHERE clause filters * @return bool - associate representing the fetched table row, false on failure */ public function delete($table, $params = array()) { // building query string $sql_str = "DELETE FROM $table"; // append WHERE if necessary $sql_str .= ( count($params)>0 ? ' WHERE ' : '' ); $add_and = false; // add each clause using parameter array foreach ($params as $key=>$val) { // only add AND after the first clause item has been appended if ($add_and) { $sql_str .= ' AND '; } else { $add_and = true; } // append clause item $sql_str .= "$key = :$key"; } // now we attempt to retrieve the row using the sql string try { $pstmt = $this->getMaster()->prepare($sql_str); // bind each parameter in the array foreach ($params as $key=>$val) { $pstmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $val); } // execute the delete query $successful_delete = $pstmt->execute(); // if we were successful, return the amount of rows updated, otherwise return false return ($successful_delete == true) ? $pstmt->rowCount() : false; } catch(PDOException $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; return false; } catch(Exception $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; return false; } } /** * method update. * - updates a row to the specified table * * @param string $table - the name of the db table we are adding row to * @param array $params - associative array representing the columns and their respective values to update * @param array $wheres (Optional) - the where clause of the query * @param bool $timestamp_this (Optional) - if true we set date_created and date_modified values to now * @return int|bool - the amount of rows updated, false on failure */ public function update($table, $params, $wheres=array(), $timestamp_this=null) { if (is_null($timestamp_this)) { $timestamp_this = self::$TIMESTAMP_WRITES; } // build the set part of the update query by // adding each parameter into the set query string $add_comma = false; $set_string = ''; foreach ($params as $key=>$val) { // only add comma after the first parameter has been appended if ($add_comma) { $set_string .= ', '; } else { $add_comma = true; } // now append the parameter $set_string .= "$key=:param_$key"; } // add the timestamp columns if neccessary if ($timestamp_this === true) { $set_string .= ($add_comma ? ', ' : '') . 'date_modified='.time(); } // lets add our where clause if we have one $where_string = ''; if (!empty($wheres)) { // load each key value pair, and implode them with an AND $where_array = array(); foreach($wheres as $key => $val) { $where_array[] = "$key=:where_$key"; } // build the final where string $where_string = 'WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where_array); } // build final update string $sql_str = "UPDATE $table SET $set_string $where_string"; // now we attempt to write this row into the database try { $pstmt = $this->getMaster()->prepare($sql_str); // bind each parameter in the array foreach ($params as $key=>$val) { $pstmt->bindValue(':param_'.$key, $val); } // bind each where item in the array foreach ($wheres as $key=>$val) { $pstmt->bindValue(':where_'.$key, $val); } // execute the update query $successful_update = $pstmt->execute(); // if we were successful, return the amount of rows updated, otherwise return false return ($successful_update == true) ? $pstmt->rowCount() : false; } catch(PDOException $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; return false; } catch(Exception $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; return false; } } /** * method insert. * - adds a row to the specified table * * @param string $table - the name of the db table we are adding row to * @param array $params - associative array representing the columns and their respective values * @param bool $timestamp_this (Optional), if true we set date_created and date_modified values to now * @return mixed - new primary key of inserted table, false on failure */ public function insert($table, $params = array(), $timestamp_this = null) { if (is_null($timestamp_this)) { $timestamp_this = self::$TIMESTAMP_WRITES; } // first we build the sql query string $columns_str = '('; $values_str = 'VALUES ('; $add_comma = false; // add each parameter into the query string foreach ($params as $key=>$val) { // only add comma after the first parameter has been appended if ($add_comma) { $columns_str .= ', '; $values_str .= ', '; } else { $add_comma = true; } // now append the parameter $columns_str .= "$key"; $values_str .= ":$key"; } // add the timestamp columns if neccessary if ($timestamp_this === true) { $columns_str .= ($add_comma ? ', ' : '') . 'date_created, date_modified'; $values_str .= ($add_comma ? ', ' : '') . 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP()'; } // close the builder strings $columns_str .= ') '; $values_str .= ')'; // build final insert string $sql_str = "INSERT INTO $table $columns_str $values_str"; // now we attempt to write this row into the database try { $pstmt = $this->getMaster()->prepare($sql_str); // bind each parameter in the array foreach ($params as $key=>$val) { $pstmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $val); } $pstmt->execute(); $newID = $this->getMaster()->lastInsertId(); // return the new id return $newID; } catch(PDOException $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; return false; } catch(Exception $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); print_r($e); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; return false; } } /** * method insertMultiple. * - adds multiple rows to a table with a single query * * @param string $table - the name of the db table we are adding row to * @param array $columns - contains the column names * @param bool $timestamp_these (Optional), if true we set date_created and date_modified values to NOW() for each row * @return mixed - new primary key of inserted table, false on failure */ public function insertMultiple($table, $columns = array(), $rows = array(), $timestamp_these = null) { if (is_null($timestamp_these)) { $timestamp_these = self::$TIMESTAMP_WRITES; } // generate the columns portion of the insert statment // adding the timestamp fields if needs be if ($timestamp_these) { $columns[] = 'date_created'; $columns[] = 'date_modified'; } $columns_str = '(' . implode(',', $columns) . ') '; // generate the values portions of the string $values_str = 'VALUES '; $add_comma = false; foreach ($rows as $row_index => $row_values) { // only add comma after the first row has been added if ($add_comma) { $values_str .= ', '; } else { $add_comma = true; } // here we will create the values string for a single row $values_str .= '('; $add_comma_forvalue = false; foreach ($row_values as $value_index => $value) { if ($add_comma_forvalue) { $values_str .= ', '; } else { $add_comma_forvalue = true; } // generate the bind variable name based on the row and column index $values_str .= ':'.$row_index.'_'.$value_index; } // append timestamps if necessary if ($timestamp_these) { $values_str .= ($add_comma_forvalue ? ', ' : '') . time().', '.time(); } $values_str .= ')'; } // build final insert string $sql_str = "INSERT INTO $table $columns_str $values_str"; // now we attempt to write this multi inster query to the database using a transaction try { $this->getMaster()->beginTransaction(); $pstmt = $this->getMaster()->prepare($sql_str); // traverse the 2d array of rows and values to bind all parameters foreach ($rows as $row_index => $row_values) { foreach ($row_values as $value_index => $value) { $pstmt->bindValue(':'.$row_index.'_'.$value_index, $value); } } // now lets execute the statement, commit the transaction and return $pstmt->execute(); $this->getMaster()->commit(); return true; } catch(PDOException $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; $this->getMaster()->rollback(); return false; } catch(Exception $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; $this->getMaster()->rollback(); return false; } } /** * method execute. * - executes a query that modifies the database * * @param string $query - the SQL query we are executing * @param bool $use_master (Optional) - whether or not to use the master connection * @return mixed - the affected rows, false on failure */ public function execute($query, $params=array()) { try { // use the master connection $pdo_connection = $this->getMaster(); // prepare the statement $pstmt = $pdo_connection->prepare($query); // bind each parameter in the array foreach ((array)$params as $key=>$val) { $pstmt->bindValue($key, $val); } // execute the query $result = $pstmt->execute(); // only if return value is false did this query fail return ($result == true) ? $pstmt->rowCount() : false; } catch(PDOException $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; return false; } catch(Exception $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; return false; } } /** * method query. * - returns data from a free form select query * * @param string $query - the SQL query we are executing * @param array $params - a list of bind parameters * @param bool $use_master (Optional) - whether or not to use the master connection * @return mixed - the affected rows, false on failure */ public function query($query, $params=array(), $use_master=false) { try { // decide which database we are selecting from $pdo_connection = $use_master ? $this->getMaster() : $this->getSlave(); $pstmt = $pdo_connection->prepare($query); // bind each parameter in the array foreach ((array)$params as $key=>$val) { $pstmt->bindValue($key, $val); } // execute the query $pstmt->execute(); // now return the results return $pstmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); } catch(PDOException $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; return false; } catch(Exception $e) { if (self::$LOG_ERRORS == true) { error_log('DATABASE WRAPPER::'.print_r($e, true)); } $this->pdo_exception = $e; return false; } } /** * method queryFirst. * - returns the first record from a free form select query * * @param string $query - the SQL query we are executing * @param array $params - a list of bind parameters * @param bool $use_master (Optional) - whether or not to use the master connection * @return mixed - the affected rows, false on failure */ public function queryFirst($query, $params=array(), $use_master=false) { $result = $this->query($query, $params, $use_master); if (empty($result)) { return false; } else { return $result[0]; } } /** * method getErrorMessage. * - returns the last error message caught */ public function getErrorMessage() { if ($this->pdo_exception) return $this->pdo_exception->getMessage(); else return 'Database temporarily unavailable'; } /** * method getError. * - returns the actual PDO exception */ public function getPDOException() { return $this->pdo_exception; } /** * Validate the database in question is supported by your installation of PHP. * @param string $driver The DSN prefix * @return boolean true, the database is supported; false, the database is not supported. */ private function validateDriver($driver) { if (!in_array($driver, PDO::getAvailableDrivers())) { return false; } else { return true; } } /** * Destructor. * - release the PDO db connections */ function __destruct() { unset($this->pdo_master); unset($this->pdo_slave); } }
```

> Notice: Undefined index: language in C:\xampp\htdocs_\config.php on
>   line 133
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: condo_name in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs_\language\fr.php on line 319
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: condo_name in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs_\language\fr.php on line 320
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: condo_name in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs_\language\fr.php on line 321
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: claim_name in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs_\language\fr.php on line 327
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: claim_name in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs_\language\fr.php on line 328
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: tender in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs_\language\fr.php on line 329
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: condo_name in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs_\language\fr.php on line 332
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: condo_name in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs_\language\fr.php on line 333
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: condo_name in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs_\language\fr.php on line 361
>
> Fatal error: Class 'PDOWrapper' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs_\index.php on line 13 etc. and a fatal error:
>
> Fatal error: Class 'PDOWrapper' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs_\index.php on line 13.

So it seems strange that it can show some PDOWrapper code content and a fatal error to find it.
I don't know why the class is not found, and the browser shows the content of the class, you can see the write, throw new Exception . . .Etc.

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I don't know why the class is not found, and the page show the content of the class, you see the write , throw new Exception . . .

Comment: _I have a page like this_ - which page? `PDOWrapper.class.php`? Can you post it here?

Comment: Updated, for page I ment browser

Comment: So, `PDOWrapper.class.php` is correctly included, but the `PDOWrapper` class doesn't (?) _Can you post it here?_

Comment: I think PDOWrapper.class.php and PDOWrapper class are the same things . . what do you need I post?

Comment: Do you have a `PDOWrapper` class in `PDOWrapper.class.php`? Have you declare a namespace for that class?

Comment: Yes I have a PDOWrapper class inide PDOWrapper.class.php, . Sorry, I am not so expert in php, what is a namespace and where i need to create it, on the server it works fine , but in local I hvae this problems

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that we can answer your question without more details. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then try to ask again